# Difference between "this" and the object name

Tags: javascript, this

Is there a difference between the 2 code snippets?

Since `foo` is a member function of `obj`, `this` would refer to `obj` itself (method invocation pattern).

**1.**

```
var obj = {};
obj.prop = some_property;
obj.foo = function() {
  do_something_with(obj.prop);
};
```

**2.**

```
var obj = {};
obj.prop = some_property;
obj.foo = function() {
  do_something_with(this.prop);
};
```

An application I was working on, kept crashing when I used approach **2**.

The code was something like :

```
obj = {};
obj.listener = {
  eventprocess : function(param) {
    //some code
  }
};
obj.init = function() {
  this.a = library_func();
  this.a.add_listener(this.listener);
};
```

it worked when I used approach **1**.

Any ideas why?

Comment: As the resolution of `obj` and `this` is deferred until execution of the function, it's result can vary depending on whether `this` or/and `obj` has changed between definition and invocation. For example, when using `this`, doing `var bar = obj.foo; bar.foo()`, will break the `this` reference but preserve the `obj`.

Comment: I recommend you to read some tutorials about the "this" keyword. The following [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/) is a pretty good one.

Comment: Had you already declared the property `obj.b` somewhere? It isn't clear from you code... But if you hadn't, and you also hadn't declared an `add_listener` property of `obj.b` then that would cause an error.

Comment: @guypursey, I'm sorry, that was a typo. It should have been `a`. Edited.

Comment: @Matt, can you write that as an answer? I overlooked the fact that resolution of `this` is deferred till execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the resolution of `obj` and `this` is deferred until execution of the function, it's result can vary depending on whether `this` or/and `obj` has changed between definition and invocation.

For example, given two objects which are identical, except one uses `this` and the other uses `obj` in the function `foo`:

```
var objA = {};
objA.prop = "test";
objA.foo = function() {
  alert(this.prop);
};

var objB = {};
objB.prop = "test";
objB.foo = function() {
  alert(objB.prop);
};
```

... we'll see different behavior here:

```
var anotherObject = {
  objAFoo: objA.foo,
  objBFoo: objB.foo
};

anotherObject.objAFoo(); // "undefined";
anotherObject.objBFoo(); // "test";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3D6xY/

Note that you can normalize this behavior by setting the value of `this` using `call()` or `apply()`, as pointed out in the comments:

```
anotherObject.objAFoo.call(objA); // "test";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3D6xY/1/

However, note also that cases where `this` has been bound using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy) can hurt you here.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that you can get `objAFoo()` to work (i.e., show the value of `objA.prop` rather than `undefined`) by using the `call` method. The method `call` allows `this` to be changed, like so: `anotherObject.objAFoo.call(objA); // "test";` [Updated JSFiddle reflects this](http://jsfiddle.net/3D6xY/1/) (no pun intended).

Comment: @guypursey: Thanks, I've incorporated that into my answer.